# How to use a JNDI resource in Spring Boot Application running on extern Tomcat8

Tags: java, spring-boot, jndi, tomcat8

I have a spring boot web-application which is deployed as war file to a Tomcat8 Server.

This Tomcat 8 Server offers the connectivityService over JNDI.

If I consume this service in normal dynamic-web-application it works just fine with this:

```
Context ctx = null;
try {
    ctx = new InitialContext();
} catch (NamingException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
ConnectivityConfiguration configuration = null;
try {
    configuration = (ConnectivityConfiguration) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/connectivityConfiguration");
} catch (NamingException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I register the resource in the web.xml with:

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>connectivityConfiguration</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>com.sap.core.connectivity.api.configuration.ConnectivityConfiguration</res-type>
  </resource-ref>
```

But if try to consume it in my Spring-Boot application it gives me this exception:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [connectivityConfiguration] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [connectivityConfiguration].
```

In my spring boot there is no web.xml, so how to register the resource?

I tried it to register it in the properties-file, but it gives me the same exception:

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:comp/env/connectivityConfiguration
```

I can't find a solution for my specific case.

I would really appreciate some guidance.

Greetings
Maverin

Comment: I got some help from a colleague.

I did provide a web.xml file under web-app\WEB-INF.

Seems there is no way to register the connectivity-service from sap via Spring-Boot in Java-Code or the propertie-files.

Comment: I have the same problem and spent to it something about two weeks of my time. Can you help me? I tried many different ways, but it's not working. Without Spring Boot, in simple web application with web.xml everything good. But in Spring Boot it looks like impossible idea.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. You just have to create the web-app\WEB-INF folder and to provide there your web.xml file.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Chris Paine As stated I had to create a web.xml where I did register the ressource.
I didn't find a way to do declare it programmatically.